# Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-managed-identity, azure-queues

I have a asp.net core 3.1 web api which adds messages to Azure Queue. In this case I am using an account to login into the VS2019 and debug the code in my local development environment. The same account is also added to the access policy for the storage account with the role : Storage Queue Data Contributor

Here I am trying to remove the dependency of using connectionstring and queue name to connect to the Azure Queue service from the asp.net core web api. All works fine in the case where I am providing connectionstring and queue name. But when I am trying to go with the route of Managed Service Identity in context to my local development environment it is throwing error.

Here goes the code for the asp.net core web api:

**TestAPIController.cs:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post([FromBody]WeatherForecast data)
    {
        var message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
        await _queueClient.SendMessageAsync(message, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
    }
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        //services.AddHostedService<WeatherDataService>();
        services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddClient<QueueClient, QueueClientOptions>((options, _, _) =>
            {
                options.MessageEncoding = QueueMessageEncoding.Base64;
                var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                var queueUri = new Uri("<AzureQueueURL>");
                return new QueueClient(queueUri, credential, options);
            });
        });
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo{Title = "queue_storage", Version = "v1"});
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "queue_storage v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

On executing the above code I found the below error:

```
Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: Azure CLI authentication failed due to an unknown error. ERROR: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

ERROR: Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS700082: The refresh token has expired due to inactivity.áThe token was issued on 2021-04-23T15:29:05.0816332Z and was inactive for 90.00:00:00.\r\nTrace ID: cbd16614-192a-409b-82a8-348597e81900\r\nCorrelation ID: 85b72955-22a3-4b1c-b05c-d7054ce6a6c6\r\nTimestamp: 2022-05-08 11:22:40Z","error_codes":[700082],"timestamp":"2022-05-08 11:22:40Z","trace_id":"cbd16614-192a-409b-82a8-348597e81900","correlation_id":"85b72955-22a3-4b1c-b05c-d7054ce6a6c6","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700082"}
```

I referred to the this article :https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/getting-started-with-azure-queue-storage/ for my POC.

Can anyone provide their guidance to fix this issue

Comment: You need to sign in again into VS2019.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri for your response. I removed the account and added it again with proper signIn process but still found the same error on subsequent validation